# Writing data frame with object dtype to HDF5 only works after converting to string

Tags: pandas, hdf5

I have a big data dataframe and I want to write it to disk for quick retrieval. I believe `to_hdf(...)` infers the data type of the columns and sometimes gets it wrong. I wonder what the correct way is to cope with this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

length = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.randint(1e7, 1e8, length),})

# df.loc[1, "a"] = "abc"
# df["a"] = df["a"].astype(str)
print(df.dtypes)
df.to_hdf("df.hdf5", key="data", format="table")
```

Uncommenting various lines leads me to the following.

- Just filling the column with numbers will lead to a data type `int32` and stores without problem
- Setting one element to `abc` changes the data to object, but it seems that `to_hdf` internally infers another data type and throws an error: `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`
- Explicitely converting the column to `str` leads to success, and `to_hdf` stores the data.

Now I am wondering what is happening in the second case, and is there a way to prevent this? The only way I found was to go through all columns, check if they are `dtype('O')` and explicitely convert them to `str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using hdf5, I have found a generic pickling library which seems to be perfect for the job: [jiblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html)

Storing and loading data is straight forward:

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(df, "file.jl")
df2 = joblib.load("file.jl")
```